# Problema con Ajax en TypeScript al hacer peticion a php

Tags: php, html, ajax, typescript, post

estoy haciendo una peticion con AJAX por POST a un archivo llamado administracion.php el cual se encarga de agregar datos a un archivo txt y guarda una foto en un directorio, la peticion se realiza bien pero al momento de retornar la peticion (*responseText*) me carga lo que hay dentro de administracion.php en el navegador en vez de imprimir la respuesta por consola.

** CODIGO AJAX **

```
let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST', './administracion.php');
    ajax.setRequestHeader("enctype","multipart/form-data");
    ajax.send(parametros);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = ():void => {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
            console.log(ajax.responseText);
        }
    };
```

Comment: ¿Estás ejecutando AJAX por medio de un evento como `submit`? Tal vez solo hace falta [cancelar el comportamiento del evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) antes de ejecutar la petición AJAX para evitar que se recargue la página.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo administracion.php retorna algo?
Prueba a hacer un array con los datos que quieres devolver y hacer un:

```
$array = ['dato1' => ['texto', 'imagen']];
echo json_encode($array); die;
```

De esta manera te aseguras que el archivo te da lo que quieres exactamente.

PD: deberías dar algo más de información con respecto al archivo al que llamas para poder ver el fallo.